# Get full filepath while unzip in UNIX

Tags: shell, unix, zip, unzip

I am stuck with one issue, and being a starter in shell script its getting confusing to achieve it.

I need to pull the file name while unzipping a file **(which contains different file with different paths)** in shell.

**Example:**

`/java/server/test/Class1.java`

`/java/server/Xml1.xml`

**Output**

I should get below as output in some local variables:

`/java/server/test/`

`/java/server/`

Note: I am using unzip utility for this.

Comment: Do I understand it well, that you just want to normally extract the files but also store all the paths to the extracted files separately (in variables or in file)?

Comment: @Fabio yes, correct !!

Answer (score 0):

If you'e got the full filename including path in $Filename then

```
${Filename##*/}
```

will give the path and

```
${Filename%/*}
```

will give the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Just unzip the file normally

```
unzip myfolder.zip
```

and then recurse through the folder and get the filepaths:

```
find $(pwd)/myfolder -type d
```

This last command gets (`find`) all folders (`-type d`) in extracted directory (`myfolder`) in the current directory (`pwd`).
Then you can redirect its output to a file

```
find $(pwd)/myfolder -type d > dirnames
```

or store it in a variable:

```
DIRNAMES=$(find $(pwd)/myfolder -type d)
```

Comment: Its not working. I extracted the file content into the directory, and then ran the second command you mentioned.

Comment: Did you run the second command in the just extracted directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can done this using combination of `sed`.

```
unzip a.zip | sed 's/.*: \(.*\)\/.*$/\1/'
```

It will give you the directory names without file names. If you need a uniq value, then use `uniq` command with that.

```
unzip a.zip | sed 's/.*: \(.*\)\/.*$/\1/' | uniq
```